# How can we create the chart UI to customisable using flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to create a below UI and we need to show the progress by the different color with percentage.please give me suggestion for that or any source to create this kind of design.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

I used Syncfusion chart but not able to do same design.